# Transforming a 3D into a 2D Plot

Tags: plotting

I have a `ListPointPlot3D` in which all points lie on a plane. I'd like to transform it into a simple 2D Plot by looking at the points from an orthogonal direction to that plane, but I don't know how to do it. (The following is a MWE, not my actual data).

```
 points = Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[1, {3}, Range[0, 1, 1/5]], 1];
 ListPointPlot3D[points]
```

Comment: Do you know the normal?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann. The plane is $x+y+z=1$, I think $(1,-1,-1)$ is normal to that (I'm a bit out of my depth in this)

Comment: We could agree on `n~{1,1,1}`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to look at the points from a viewpoint perpendicular to the plane without distortion, you must first determine a vector that is perpendicular. You can do this using the cross product of the three first points:

```
perp=Cross[points[[2]]-points[[1]],points[[3]]-points[[1]]];
```

perp is now perpendicular. To eliminate the perspective distortion we multiply it with a large number . Finally we can set the viewpoint:

```
ListPointPlot3D[points, ViewPoint -> 100 perp, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate the box altogether? I've tried ```Axes->None``` to no avail.

Comment: Use: Axes -> None, Boxed -> False

Comment: I thought that from an orthogonal perspective, the triangle would look equilateral

Comment: Of course you are right. All 3 axis should be represented with equal length. To achieve this, we need: BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 4):

If we know the normal direction `n~ {1,1,1}` we can define an orthonormal coordinate system `{e1,e2,n}`

```
n = #/Sqrt[#.#] &[{1, 1, 1}];
e2 = #/Sqrt[#.#] &[Cross[n, {1, -1, 0}] ]
e1 = #/Sqrt[#.#] &[Cross[n, e1]]
```

`e1,e2` both lie in the plane.

Projection of the `points` normal to `n`

```
pe=Map[# - n (n.#) &, points];(* pe normal to n *)
```

Plot the points in the `e1,e2` system

```
ListPlot[Map[{#.e1, #.e2} &, pe], AxesLabel -> {"e1", "e2"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does your procedure do explicitly what @DanielHuber's does implicitly?

Comment: @Patricio My "procedure" performs the projection into a plane (defined by `n`) and returns finally the coordinates in the `e1,e2` system (2D) . The choice of the plane coordinate system `e1,e2` isn't unique.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

3D method

```
points = Flatten[
   Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[1, {3}, Range[0, 1, 1/5]], 1];
ListPointPlot3D[points, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

**2D method**

We can rotate the normal vector `{1,1,1}` to `{0,0,1}` and make the plane parallel to the x-y plane ,after that we can  project the points to the x-y plane just by erase the third coordinate.

```
points = Flatten[
   Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[1, {3}, Range[0, 1, 1/5]], 1];
rotation = RotationMatrix[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}];
pts = Table[rotation.point, {point, points}];
newpoints = Drop[#, -1] & /@ pts;
ListPlot[newpoints, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Your 2D method is a projection `~ {0,0,1}`! That's not the direction of the normal I think.